# BigQuery Global Alias of Wildcard for Self Join

Tags: google-bigquery

Often I need to join a table to itself, and based on the match predicate, print out all the columns from both tables. e.g

`` SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM `t` t1
JOIN `t` t2
USING(Id)
WHERE xxxx ``

Issue with this is that you get column name collisions since they are the same source table / cols in each.

Is there a way to avoid this but still use a '*'?  I checked the doco and cant see any option in standardSQL

Ideally Id just want a prefix to be applied to the wildcard projections, rather then hand alias each col individually / manually, as a lot of our tables are really wide, and change, and hand cranking is just laborious

e.g Id like to be able to do something like this to prefix each of T2's columns with the string "t2_"

`` SELECT t1.*, t2.* PREFIX("t2_")
FROM `t` t1
JOIN `t` t2
USING(Id)
WHERE xxxx ``

Currently there is likely not a solution as clean as this, unless I missed it in the doco (hope so!), if there are any interim SQL solution using other methods please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: what the practical use of having duplicates of all columns in the output?

Comment: i think I can see few such use cases :o) but still curious about what exactly yours - if you can share

Comment: My use case is comparing the output (delta/differences) of a bq release (e.g a view) against a golden reference table thats certified from the previous release. Form of regression testing of our views. They are the same table output, same columns, but I want to find the differences, and when I do, output all the cols from both golden and current release.

Comment: also the reason for flattening is Tableau (where we report on bq regression results) prefers such data flat unfortunately....Elliotts response below achieves the general need except for flattening.

Comment: was building some generic table compare SQL using TO_JSON_STRING, was just trying to flatten the output rather then have a top level record/struct....thanks!

Comment: Make sense. This was exactly what I thought your use case could be. Thank you for sharing

Comment: Ha - thank you, I use your advice on here often, you're a top person and love your contribution to a product that is near and dear to my heat! :) . So thank you too

Comment: wow. thank you for nice words. they inspired me to provide you with new answer :o) hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

Below approach is a little controversial as it points back to features in BigQuery Legacy SQL - but why not to use them when it is handy :o)

So, below is   for BigQuery Legacy SQL and you can use it to get result that you need. In case if you will need features of Standard SQL to further process that result  - you can just simply preserve it in the temp table and than use for further processing

Meantime, below code does not require you to specify columns and result is flattened

```
#legacySQL
SELECT *
FROM [project:dataset.table] t1
JOIN [project:dataset.table] t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id  
WHERE xxxx
```

The trick here is that all columns from table aliased as t1 - will be prefixed with `t1_` like `t1_col1, t1_col2` and so on ; and all column from t2 will be prefixed with `t2_` like `t2_col1, t2_col2` and so on - so no `column name collisions`

Comment: Cool! I always have the problem of a standardSQL view not being able to call a  legacySQL one for such feature gaps, but, for my use case that might not be a problem in this instance....let me give it a go.....thanks and keep up the fantastic community hero work for BQ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just select `t1` and `t2` instead:

```
SELECT t1, t2 FROM `t` t1 JOIN `t` t2 USING(Id) WHERE xxxx
```

Comment: lol - nice simple option :) . I was trying to flatten the whole result set is the only thing, but, maybe this will need to do.  Appreciated.